# Setting angular directive name via model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-directives

I've got a loop where based on the value, I need to specify a particular directive. Here is what I've got:

```
<div ng-repeat="w in row.widgets" class="col-md-{{12/row.widgets.length}}">
                    <{{w.type}}>
                    </{{w.type}}>
                </div>
```

The thing is, I've got matching directives already setup however rather than actually call the directive, the markup output is simply

```
<widget-directive-one>
<widget-directive-two>
<widget-directive-three>
```

I don't understand why rather than output the actual value, it won't call upon the directive of the same name. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Attribute names  and tag names can't be dynamically generated in the dom itself (views).

Angular needs to be able to parse elements in the dom and compare existing tag names or attributes to those directives

There are numerous ways to approach this ... `ng-switch` , `ng-if` or a custom directive that returns the directive tag you want are several examples

Answer (score 0):

Add a widgetType to your controller $scope. Then you can do something like this:

```
<div ng-switch="widgetType">
  <widget-one ng-switch-when="widgetOne"></widget-one>
  <widget-two ng-switch-when="widgetTwo"></widget-two>
  <widget-three ng-switch-when="widgetThree"></widget-three>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this **ng-if**

```
<div ng-repeat="w in row.widgets" class="col-md-{{12/row.widgets.length}}">
    <widget-directive-one ng-if="$index==0"></widget-directive-one>
    <widget-directive-two ng-if="$index==1"></widget-directive-two>
    <widget-directive-three ng-if="$index==2"></widget-directive-three>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-bind-html` directive:

From the Docs:

> ### ngBindHtml
>
> Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way.
>
> You may also bypass sanitization for values you know are safe. To do so, bind to an explicitly trusted value via [$sce.trustAsHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml). See the example under [Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#show-me-an-example-using-sce-).

-- [AngularJS ng-bind-html Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)